# Transfering from multiple accounts?

Tags: rpc, sub-address, transfer

I see in the [wallet RPC documentation](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer) that the `transfer` command can take the `account_index` and `subaddr_indices` arguments. Are these optional? What happens if these are not specified? Can the `transfer` command send Moneroj from multiple accounts and/or subaddresses on the same wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, if not specified, `account_index` will default to 0, while `subaddr_indices` will allow the wallet to use outputs from specified sub-address indexes as inputs.
If you specify multiple `subaddr_indices`, you restrain the wallet to only pick from those. But it will depend on the outputs available and the amount you want to transfer. It could pick one from one subaddresses, or more from the same or from other subaddresses.
However, you cannot send from multiple accounts at the same time.

Comment: You are correct. They are both optional.

Comment: Thank you both. I asked because the API docs do not indicate these arguments as optional, while other arguments are indeed marked optional.

Comment: The upcoming refresh of this doc will indicate it's optional.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Subaddress](https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/#group-funds-into-accounts) documentation:

> Thus, a single transaction can - in principle - aggregate and spend
> outputs from multiple addresses (and by extension from multiple
> accounts). The CLI or GUI wallet may not directly support creating
> such transactions for simplicity.

It seems that at the present moment, neither the Monero GUI/RPC/CLI wallets implement the ability to transfer from multiple addresses.